# What's the Hochschild homology of the category of constructible sheaves?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a manifold.  Does the Hochschild homology/cohomology of the category of constructible sheaves on $X$ have a more familiar name?

Comment: Aren't there some subtleties in the definition of a HH_* for an $\infty$-category which is not compactly generated? How do you define it?

Comment: It's defined for any dualizable $\infty$-category (presentable say), not necessarily compactly generated, as the composition of evaluation and coevaluation maps.. then again it's harder to show you're dualizable without compact generation...